# How to get a ranking of frequency of elements in a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame named `a`. I want to get the top two most frequent elements in each row.
`Input:`

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame({'A1':['food','movie','sport'],'A2':['game','traffic','health'],
'A3':['food','health','education'],'A4':['game','travel','other'],
'A5':['social','other','sport']})
```

`Output:`

```
      A1       A2         A3      A4      A5
0   food     game       food    game  social
1  movie  traffic     health  travel   other
2  sport   health  education   other   sport
```

`Expected:`

```
      top1       top2 
0   food     game    
1  health    movie    
2  sport   education
```

As you see, maybe some elements in a row appear at the same frequency.For such elements, I just select one of them for ranking, for example, all of elements in row `1` appear once, so I just randomly select two of them for ranking.

Hopefully for help and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

tops = [
    [*zip(*Counter(r).most_common(2))][0]
    for r in zip(*map(a.get, a))
]

pd.DataFrame(tops, a.index, ['top1', 'top2'])

    top1     top2
0   food     game
1  movie  traffic
2  sport   health
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try of using value counts and assign most occuring word as top and so on

```
pd.DataFrame({'top1':a.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0],1 ).values,
              'top2':a.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[1],1 ).values})
```

Out:

```
    top1    top2
0   game    food
1   traffic movie
2   sport   other
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
a.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.value_counts().nlargest(2).index.tolist(), 
                            index=['top1','top2']), 
       axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      top1   top2
0     game   food
1  traffic  other
2    sport  other
```

Answer (score 0):

you need Counter and apply functions,

```
from collections import Counter
out_df=pd.DataFrame((df.apply(Counter,axis=1).apply(list).str[:2]).values.tolist(),columns=['top1','top2'])
```